# Beautiful Soup scraping BBC Sport website - I want to ignore 'Scottish Championship' but show 'Championship'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am scraping from: "https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/scores-fixtures/" + chosen_date

[image: screenshot of BBC Sport website]

This is my array:

`leagues = (['~Scottish Championship', 'Championship'])`

I want to extract just 'Championship' and ignore 'Scottish Championship', but I am currently getting the output like this:

[image: screenshot of output]

What's wrong in my array? This didn't work either:

`leagues = (['^((?!Scottish Championship).)*$', 'Championship'])`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure how you're using your array but if you just want to filter and get the HTML from within "Championship", here is one possible solution. Let me know if this answers your question.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/scores-fixtures/2021-12-04"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "qa-match-block"})
for div in results:
    something = div.find('h3')
    if (something.text == 'Championship'):
        # do something with that div from championship...
```

If you wanted to use some array or list, then you could do:

```
if (something.text in my_list)
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm looking to make my array display the avoidance of the Scottish Championship or exactly match Championship.

Comment: So, I think it would exactly match Championship if you used: 

```(something.text in ['Championship'])``` if you are forcing yourself to use an array.